# Strange floating box issues

Tags: html, css, debugging, css-float, internet-explorer-7

If I used the following code:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <p>varying lines of text</p>
    </td><td>
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <p>varying lines of text</p>
    </td></tr><tr><td>
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <p>varying lines of text</p>
    </td><td>
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <p>varying lines of text</p>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

I would have no problems using CSS on it, but as the future progresses, I'll have a gut feeling future browsers will depreciate more table functionality. I'm trying to achieve the same thing but with DIV tags and CSS and I want to make it compatible with older web browsers such as Internet Explorer 7.

This is the code I have:

CSS:

```
.stretch{width:100%;overflow:hidden}
.common{float:left;margin:0.2em;padding:0.1em;width:40%}
```

HTML:

```
<div ID="outer" class="stretch">
    <div class="common">
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <p>varying lines of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="common">
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <p>varying lines of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="common">
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <p>varying lines of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="common">
        <h3>Header</h3>
        <p>varying lines of text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tested it in firefox 15 and opera 11.6 on my natural desktop size of 800x600 and the boxes line up correctly. When I use the zoom tools in both browsers to zoom out to emulate a 1024x768 screen, the last two boxes do not align side-by-side. it's more like a 3 row by two column grid with some pieces missing. However, I went down to a 50% zoom (to emulate a 1600x1200 screen) and the box arrangement is correct.

Each box contains a variable amount of text.

Why does this happen and is there a way to fix this or do I have to return to using tables?

Comment: did you try to use `Media Query` ?

Comment: no but I'm gonna try extra divs

Answer (score 1):

I'm settling for this:

```
<div ID="outer" class="stretch">
<div class="common">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p>varying lines of text</p>
</div>
<div class="common">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p>varying lines of text</p>
</div>
</div>
<div ID="outer2" class="stretch">
<div class="common">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p>varying lines of text</p>
</div>
<div class="common">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <p>varying lines of text</p>
</div>
</div>
```

This works best for me since I only have one row of divs per box and therefore never have to worry about having the boxes screwed up. Only caveat which I'm ok with is that in this version, using a border of a different colour will show a line running through between the top and bottom boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use viewports for everything. The advantage being they work off total viewable area, whether or not it's a parent or child element. Thus, you can create a fully responsive webpage.

```
.stretch{width:100%;overflow:hidden}
.common{float:left;margin:0.5vh;padding:0.5vh;width:40vw}
```

Something like that would make it more adaptable. You just need to make sure your parent divs for a "row" are 100vw.

Comment: except I don't think IE7 supports that nor do other older web browsers.